# Can't download from a https address using wget

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, wget

I'm trying to download some videos from [DefCon archive](https://www.defcon.org/html/links/dc-archives/dc-20-archive.html) using `wget` but i'm getting this:

```
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I tried to use `wget` with `--no-check-certificate` but got the same result.
What is the problem?
How can I force wget to download the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is at their end as I get the same issue when using a web browser, curl, wget and openssl client

~$ openssl s_client -connect media.defcon.org:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
15891:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:

Comment: Thanks; I [reported the problem on their forum](https://forum.defcon.org/showthread.php?t=13462) and they approved it;

Answer (score 0):

Their [torrent page](https://www.defcon.org/html/links/dc-torrent.html) works for me:

```
$ aria2c "https://www.defcon.org/html/torrent/DEF%20CON%2020%20hacker%20pyramid.torrent"
[#8c954b 0B/0B CN:1 DL:0B]
06/30 18:47:41 [NOTICE] Download complete: /home/dawud/downloads/DEF CON 20 hacker pyramid.torrent

06/30 18:47:41 [NOTICE] IPv4 DHT: listening on UDP port 6889

06/30 18:47:41 [NOTICE] IPv4 BitTorrent: listening on TCP port 6881

 *** Download Progress Summary as of Sun Jun 30 18:48:40 2013 ***
=================================================================================================================================================================================================================================

[#0f5992 16MiB/815MiB(2%) CN:2 SD:2 DL:287KiB ETA:47m24s]
```

Comment: Yes; it seems the problem only occure on the `media` subdomain. they approved the problem (see my comment on Epphus's answer)